# Searching for the name of a Sci Fi illustrated story from approx 1970s about a never ending war

Tags: story-identification, warfare, illustrated-story

The story is set far into the future, not on Earth, about two nations that have been at war for as long as can be remembered but the origins of the war have now been forgotten. 
I seem to remember that the two factions are illustrated with one nation using blue uniforms and the other using red uniforms. A soldier on each side decides that the war is pointless and they must find a way to bring it to an end
The story was in the format of an annual-sized book, in full colour.
I'd be grateful for any help as I've been trying to track down a copy for years but need to find out the title .

Comment: Hmm...its remind me `ben 10 alien force season 3 episode 5 simple` , may be that episode is inspired from this story

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I can't say I've ever seen any Ben-10, so I can't comment on that one, but it's definitely not The Butter Battle Book. It was definitely proper Sci-Fi, on another planet with futuristic weaponry, etc. I've tried searching the web but whenever a search string mentions sci-fi combined to a long-lasting war, it always turns up Joe Halderman's 'Forever War'. I can't find a valid search string that focusses in on an illustrated story that fits the description I gave.
Thanks again for the suggestions, though.
Cheers
Karl

Answer (score 3):

Were the full-colour illustrations photographs? If so, then you might have been reading the novelization of the Star Trek episode "A Taste of Armageddon," which was illustrated with still photos from the television show.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that it's The Butter Battle Book http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Butter_Battle_Book  Like the article says it's inspired by Gulliver's Travels and the Cold War. It's been a while since I've seen it or read it but I seem to remember two people trying to stop the arms race some how, that could just be a faulty memory though since the article doesn't mention it.